# WaveInEvent sample event frequency

Tags: naudio

I'm using the code block below to receive samples from my microphone and pass them to an RTP channel on a SIP call. The problem is the samples are arriving every 200ms whereas I'm expecting them every 20ms. The samples are the right size for a 20ms sampling interval at 20ms it's just that the 20ms samples only arrive every 200ms. I'm probably doing something silly with my WaveInEvent set up?

```
var _waveInEvent = new WaveInEvent();
_waveInEvent.BufferMilliseconds = 20;
_waveInEvent.NumberOfBuffers = 1;
_waveInEvent.DeviceNumber = 0;
_waveInEvent.DataAvailable += RTPChannelSampleAvailable;
_waveInEvent.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally have at least two buffers, so you can be examining one while another is filled.
20ms might be a little bit quick for WaveIn to cope with. Check how many bytes are in the DataAvailable callback buffer. With your values, you should be getting 320 bytes at a time.

Comment: I am getting 320 bytes at a time but for some reason every 200ms rather than every 20ms.

Comment: OK, so the buffer size is right, it's not just keeping up. Try 2 or 3 buffers and 100ms and see what frequency you get.

Comment: That worked. I was able to use 50ms and 4 buffers (not sure if that makes a difference) and get samples every 50ms. Will NAudio ever queue buffers up? I mean can I rely on the DataAvailable event firing for each and every sample or could one event have two or more samples queued up?

Comment: I spoke too soon the 50ms case looks like it may have been a fluke. Subsequent attempts @50ms have resulted in a sample period of 200ms. The 100ms case still works though. The problem I've got is even at 50ms the sample period is too great for a SIP call as a lot of clients use 50ms as the jitter buffer size and drop any RTP packets that arrive after that. I suspect NAudio, being based on .Net, is unlikely ever to be able to give me microphone samples @ 20ms or 30ms?

Comment: If you can do without Windows XP support, you could try WASAPI, which is a little closer to the metal and might give you lower latency